# CSS last-child causing unexpected results

Tags: css, wordpress, css-selectors

I am using a Wordpress reset theme and designing a child theme from scratch.  The menu (nav) of this site will include drop down menus, which are working.  The following is the menu structure (auto generated in WP):

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation">
  <div class="menu-menu-1-container">
    <ul id="menu-menu-1" class="menu">
      <li id="menu-item-20" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page current-menu-item page_item page-item-4 current_page_item menu-item-20"><a href="http://somesite.com/">Home</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-21" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-21"><a href="http://somesite.com/about-us/">About Us</a></li>
      <li id="menu-item-22" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-has-children menu-item-22"><a href="http://somesite.com/admissions/">Admissions</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
          <li id="menu-item-27" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-27"><a href="http://somesite.com/sample-page/">Sample Page</a></li>
          <li id="menu-item-28" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-28"><a href="http://somesite.com/sample-page-2/">Sample Page 2</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li id="menu-item-24" class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-object-page menu-item-24"><a href="http://somesite.com/contact-us/">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Everything is working fine. With that and with the dropdown. I have this in the CSS which works but also puts a right border on the last menu item (CONTACT US):

```
header #nav li a
{
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-right: 1px solid #000;
    margin-right: 9px;
    padding: 0px 9px 0px 0px;       
}
```

However, when I add this:

```
header #nav ul li a:last-child
{
    border-right: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

I get this:
[image: Image after adding last-child]

It's like it affects every "a" except for the one with a nest UL under it.

Any thoughts on why this is happening and how to correct it? I only want to affect CONTACT.

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `:last-child` you used is referring to "the last `a` in *every* `li`". You need to use the following instead:

```
header #nav ul li:last-child a
{
    border-right: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!  Now that I see it, it makes perfect sense for the last-child pseudo to be on the li and not the a.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
#nav > .menu-menu-1-container > ul > li:last-child > a{
    border-right: none;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

`>` is used to refer the direct child only.

**or**

```
#menu-item-24 > a{
    /* css style here */
}
```

if the above id is unique.